# Table que mostra só algumas colunas do banco de dados

Tags: php, html, mysql

**Tenho um sistema que:**

Em uma página tem um filtro de busca que quando preenchido leva a outra página com uma tabela que só mostra os registros que atendem as restrições exigidas pelo filtro.

A única maneira que eu sei de fazer uma tabela que mostra os registros do banco filtrados é imprimindo a tabela igual a do banco.

Só que pra essa página eu queria uma tabela mostrasse só algumas colunas dos registros filtrados, mas eu não sei como fazer isso.

**Essa é a página do filtro:**

```
<?php 
    require 'strcon.php';
    $queryConsult = mysqli_query ($strcon, "SELECT * FROM  `pedidos` ORDER BY  `pedidos`.`CONSULTORIO` ASC"); 
    $id            = ISSET($_POST["ID"]);
    $consultorio      = ISSET($_POST["CONSULTORIO"]);
?>
<?php 
    require 'strcon.php';
    $queryAno = mysqli_query ($strcon, "SELECT * FROM  `pedidos` ORDER BY  `pedidos`.`ANO` ASC"); 
    $ida            = ISSET($_POST["ID"]);
    $ano      = ISSET($_POST["ANO"]);
?>


<form method="post" action="nota-pag.php">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="CONSULTORIO">Consulorio: </label>
            <select  class="form-control" id="CONSULTORIO" name="CONSULTORIO">
                <option>Selecione...</option>
                <?php while($consult = mysqli_fetch_array($queryConsult)) { ?> 
                <option value="<?php echo $consult['CONSULTORIO']; ?>"><?php echo $consult['CONSULTORIO']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ANO">Ano: </label>
            <select  class="form-control" id="ANO" name="ANO">
                <option>Selecione...</option>
                <?php while($ano = mysqli_fetch_array($queryAno)) { ?> 
                <option value="<?php echo $ano['ANO']; ?>"><?php echo $ano['ANO']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="MES">Mês: </label>
            <select  class="form-control" id="MES" name="MES">
                <option>Selecione...</option>
                <option>JAN</option>
                <option>FEV</option>
                <option>MAR</option>
                <option>ABR</option>
                <option>MAI</option>
                <option>JUN</option>
                <option>JUL</option>
                <option>AGO</option>
                <option>SET</option>
                <option>OUT</option>
                <option>NOV</option>
                <option>DEZ</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 22;">Buscar</button>
</form>
```

**E essa é a página que mostra a tabela filtrada:**

```
<!--content--> 
<?php error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    $lnk = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysqli_error()) or die ('Nao foi possível conectar ao MySql: ' . mysqli_error($lnk));
    mysqli_select_db($lnk,'sis_tam') or die ('Nao foi possível ao banco de dados selecionado no MySql: ' . mysqli_error($lnk));

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM pedidos ORDER BY CONSULTORIO, MES, ANO ASC';
    $consultorio = $_POST['CONSULTORIO'];
    $mes = $_POST['MES'];
    $ano = $_POST['ANO'];

    if(!is_null($consultorio) && !empty($consultorio)) 
        $sqli = "SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE CONSULTORIO LIKE '%".$consultorio."%' AND MES LIKE '%".$mes."%'";

    $qry = mysqli_query($lnk, $sqli) or die(mysqli_error($lnk));
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($qry);
    $num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($qry);//Obtém o número de campos do resultado
    //$fields[] = array();
    if($num_fields > 0) {
        for($i = 0;$i<$num_fields; $i++){//Pega o nome dos campos
            $fields[] = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($qry,$i)->name;
        }
    } 
?>

<body>

<!--Tabela com as buscas-->
<?php
//Montando o cabeçalho da tabela
$table = '<table class="table table-hover table-inverse" style="margin-top:50;background-color: #881216; color:lightgrey;"> <tr>';

for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
    $table .= '<th>'.$fields[$i].'</th>';
}

//Montando o corpo da tabela
$table .= '<tbody style="
    background-color: #86979e;
    color: #37444a;    
">';
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)){
    $table .= '<tr>';
    for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
        $table .= '<td>'.$r[$fields[$i]].'</td>';
    }

    // Adicionando botão de edição

                $table .= '</form></td>';
            }
            //Finalizando a tabela
            $table .= '</tbody></table>';

            //Imprimindo a tabela
            echo '<div class="table-table" style="overflow-x:auto;">';
            echo $table;
            echo '</div>';

?>
```

**Essa é a minha tabela:**

ID, DENTISTA,   PACIENTE,   CONSULTORIO,    SERVICO,    IDSERV, ADICIONAIS, SOLICITACAO,    PREVISAO,   VALOR,  ACERTO, SALDO,  MES,    ANO,    STATUS

**As colunas que eu queria que mostrasse são essas:**

ID, DENTISTA, CONSULTORIO, SERVICO, VALOR, MES

Alguém pode me mostrar como fazer isso? Obrigada. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de colocar,

```
SELECT * FROM pedidos
```

só colocar o seguinte:

```
SELECT ID, DENTISTA, CONSULTORIO, SERVICO, VALOR, MES FROM pedidos
```

Comment: Isso no $sql ou no $sqli?

Comment: Olha, resolveu. Obrigada!

Comment: @MarianaFerreira Marcar a resposta como correta, obrigado.

Comment: Sim, eu só estava esperando dar o tempo mínimo